# spring boot batch, execution date stuck with wrong value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application with spring boot with the following config class:

```
   @Bean
public Job myaJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                           Step extractAccounts,
                           Step transformAccounts,
                           Step writeOutputFile) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME)
                            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                            .flow(extractAccounts)
                            .next(transformAccounts)
                            .next(writeOutputFile)
                            .end()
                            .build();
}
```

main class

```
@Log4j2
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
Job myJob;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
}

@SneakyThrows
@Override
public void run(String... args) {

    JobParameters jobParameters = buildJobParameters();
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(myJob, jobParameters);

}


protected JobParameters buildJobParameters() {

    return new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("executionDate", new Date())
                                     .toJobParameters();

}
```

the problem is that the batch is executed twice each time I run the application, all the steps are called twice and even the job is called twice, but when I remove all the code of `public void run(String... args)`, the batch is executed normally once as expected, but the parameter execution_date is stuck with the last value used before removing the code.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, just use

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

inside application.properties or application.yml so the job will be executed once.